# Is there an Elasticsearch aggregation for dates equivalent to GeoTile Grid?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Let's say I have some time based data like this:

```
POST /events/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{"_id":1}}
{"timestamp": "2019-06-07T01:55:23.432+00:00", "type": "enter"}
{"index":{"_id":2}}
{"timestamp": "2019-06-07T01:58:33.100+00:00", "type": "exit"}
{"index":{"_id":3}}
{"timestamp": "2019-06-07T02:03:04.867+00:00", "type": "exit"}
{"index":{"_id":4}}
{"timestamp": "2019-06-07T02:12:11.108+00:00", "type": "enter"}
{"index":{"_id":5}}
{"timestamp": "2019-06-07T02:22:58.771+00:00", "type": "enter"}
{"index":{"_id":6}}
{"timestamp": "2019-06-07T03:37:28.844+00:00", "type": "exit"}
```

And I want to group events that happened within 15 minutes of each other, much like [GeoTile Grid](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/search-aggregations-bucket-geotilegrid-aggregation.html) groups points that are geographically near each other.

The resulting response would look like this:

```
{
    ...
    "aggregations": {
        "time-clumps": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                  "from" : "2019-06-07T01:55:23.432+00:00",
                  "to"   : "2019-06-07T02:10:23.432+00:00",
                  "doc_count" : 3
                },
                {
                  "from" : "2019-06-07T02:12:11.108+00:00",
                  "to"   : "2019-06-07T02:27:11.108+00:00",
                  "doc_count" : 2
                },
                {
                  "from" : "2019-06-07T03:37:28.844+00:00",
                  "to"   : "2019-06-07T03:52:28.844+00:00",
                  "doc_count" : 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some way to write this query in Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with the [`date_histogram` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html):

```
POST /events/_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "time-clumps" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval" : "15m"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My first hunch. But histogram splits events near the border into different buckets. I need someway for the border to be dynamic and dependent on the data.

Comment: What do you mean by "border"?